# CodeIgniter can't find GearmanClient

Tags: php, codeigniter, classnotfoundexception, gearman

I have setup gearman for my Apache/CodeIgniter server.

I got this output when running:

> php -i | grep gearman

[image]

I am able to create a GearmanClient using command line.

```
 $gmclient = new GearmanClient();
 $gmclient->addServer($id);
```

I just can't create a GearmanClient in CodeIgniter controller. 
Keep getting this error:

> class not found GearmanClient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if Gearman extensions is enabled for all [SAPIs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Application_Programming_Interface).

Could be namespace problem. Try using [fully qualified name](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rules.php) `$gmclient = new \GearmanClient();` See [How do I use  internal or global classes in a namespace?](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.faq.php#language.namespaces.faq.globalclass)